# MIN(column) with subquery

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How do I query 3 tables (STUDENTS, MODULES, MARKS) such that I return the module name and the lowest mark score for student John Doe?

```
SQL> DESC STUDENTS;
 Name                    Null?    Type
 STUDENT_NO                       VARCHAR2(10)
 SURNAME                          VARCHAR2(20)
 FORENAME                         VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> DESC MODULES;
 Name                    Null?    Type
 MODULE_CODE                      VARCHAR2(8)
 MODULE_NAME                      VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> DESC MARKS;
 Name                    Null?    Type
 STUDENT_NO                       VARCHAR2(10)
 MODULE_CODE                      VARCHAR2(8)
 MARK                             NUMBER(38)
```

I have:

```
SQL> SELECT MOD.MODULE_NAME, MA.MARK 
    FROM MODULES MOD 
        INNER JOIN MARKS MA ON(MOD.MODULE_CODE = MA.MODULE_CODE) 
    WHERE MA.STUDENT_NO = (SELECT S.STUDENT_NO FROM STUDENTS S WHERE S.SURNAME = 'Doe');
```

MODULE_NAME                MARK
Databases                    80
Programming                  65
Operating Systems            50
 but cannot get it to display the lowest value.
Trying to put a MIN(MA.MARKS) in the SELECT clause or after the WHERE clause causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this:

```
SELECT MOD.MODULE_NAME, MA.MARK 
FROM MODULES MOD INNER 
JOIN MARKS MA ON(MOD.MODULE_CODE = MA.MODULE_CODE) 
WHERE MA.STUDENT_NO = 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT S.STUDENT_NO 
    FROM STUDENTS S 
    WHERE S.SURNAME = 'Lothbrock'
) 
AND MARKS.MARK = 
(
    SELECT MIN(MARKS.MARK) 
    FROM MARKS
) 
ORDER BY MA.MARK;
```

Now I just have to figure out how to implement "LIMIT 1" in SQL*Plus...

Answer (score 4):

Why would this not be sufficient?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT MOD.MODULE_NAME, MA.MARK
  FROM MODULES MOD 
  JOIN MARKS MA ON (MOD.MODULE_CODE = MA.MODULE_CODE) 
  JOIN STUDENTS S ON (S.STUDENT_NO = MA.STUDENT_NO)
  WHERE S.SURNAME = 'Doe'
  ORDER BY 2) x
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've gone for a simple sub-query approach partly because I like the ROW_NUMBER functionality. So this lists the marks per module is ascending order in the inner query and then just returns the values for the first row number returned.

```
SQL> select * from wg_student
2  /
STUDENT_NO SURNAME              FORENAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
     1 Doe                  John
SQL> select * from wg_module
2  /
MODULE_C MODULE_NAME
-------- --------------------
DB       Databases
PR       Programming
OS       Operating Systems
SQL> select * from wg_mark
2  /
STUDENT_NO MODULE_C       MARK
---------- -------- ----------
     1 DB               80
     1 DB               90
     1 PR               65
     1 PR               80
     1 OS               75
     1 OS               50
6 rows selected.
SQL> SELECT sub_query.module_name, sub_query.mark
 2  FROM (SELECT mod.module_name, ma.mark, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ma.mark ASC) rn
3            FROM wg_module mod
4                 INNER JOIN wg_mark ma ON (mod.module_code = ma.module_code)
5                 INNER JOIN wg_student st ON (ma.student_no = st.student_no)
6           WHERE st.surname = 'Doe') sub_query
7   WHERE sub_query.rn = 1
8  /
MODULE_NAME                MARK
-------------------- ----------
Databases                    80
Operating Systems            50
Programming                  65
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a subquery? You could, but this may be a bit easier. Not tested this as I didn't have time to create the tables and fill data. You could try this:

```
select -- stu.name, 
   mod.module_name,
   min(mar.mark) mark_score
from modules mod
join marks mar
  on (mar.module_code = mod.module_code)
join students stu
  on (stu.student_no = mar.student_no)
where stu.name = 'John Doe'
group by mod.module_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what environment you're in, but this is a good case for windowing/partitioning functions. For you, if you wanted to find the lowest score for each student and in what module, it would just be

```
select x.*
from (
select student_no, module_code, row_number()over(partition by student_no order by mark asc) rownum from #test
) x
where x.rownum = 1;
```

but if you're not using a db environment that doesn't support windowing, then you could use subqueries.

EDIT: I would change this query to use the RANK() function just in case you have two modules with the same grade like this:

```
select x.*
from (
select student_no, module_code, RANK()over(partition by student_no order by mark asc) rownum from #test
) x
where x.rownum = 1;
```